# Sign in with fingerprint in oauth 2.0

Tags: android, rest, oauth-2.0, android-fingerprint-api

I have a REST api secured with an OAuth 2.0 authentication model. Now I have a client that would like to develop a mobile application (Android) that will use this API. This applicaiton will use the built in fingerprint scanner inn Android for login. Do anyone have any suggestions for how this application should do the authentication against my OAuth 2.0 service? When we have created mobile applications before, we have used the standard Oauth login where the application opens the default browser and logs in using the standard Oauth login process, but what to do if the user should be able to login using fingerprint?

Comment: Hi, finally you made it? 
thanks!

Answer (score 9):

We solved this using regular Oauth and a refresh token. We log in to the applications once using the default oauth flow, and then we store the refresh token, but the user have to authenticate using fingerprint to be able to fetch the refresh token and then the application will exchange the refresh token for an access token.

Comment: but refresh tokens have a validity of 30 minutes(ideally). How do you achieve this? Did u increase the validity of refresh token? If so is it safe to do so. Would love to know more about it. We are facing the same dilemma.

Comment: @pvpkiran Actually refresh tokens can be valid even for years. It's just a security consideration. Refresh tokens also can be replaced with new refresh tokens while getting access tokens before they expire.

Answer (score 1):

How about using auth0 services for server side and client side?

1. Implement biometric authentication at client side ([install android sdk](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-android)) for sending auth state to the server side
2. Implement logic at server side for receiving auth state from the client and use that state to authenticate users with your OAuth solution [uses non interactive client](https://auth0.com/docs/clients/client-settings/non-interactive)

Or you can use only the auth0 services to achieve what you want

Comment: Thank you, but auth0 is not an alternative for me right now.